# How to replace Backslash '\' with double Backslash in Dart?

Tags: regex, dart, flutter, replaceall

How to replace a Single Backslash '\' in a String with double Backslash '\' ?

I tried this, but its not working.

```
main(){
String string = "back\slash back\slash back\slash back\slash";
String replaced = string.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\\'), '\\\\');
print(replaced);
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What output do you get?

Comment: No error , just I was unable to accomplish what I needed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that the string `string` does not contain any `\`

It would either need to be

```
String string = r"back\slash back\slash back\slash back\slash";
```

or

```
String string = "back\\slash back\\slash back\\slash back\\slash";
```

In your example there also is no need for RegExp.
Just

```
String replaced = string.replaceAll(r'\', r'\\');
```

would do as well.

Comment: This has to do with how Dart handles raw strings, for further explanation see [How to Create A Raw String In Dart](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-create-a-raw-string-in-dart)