# show image from database that has backslash instead slash in path in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, image-flutter

I save my image in database with backslash (\) in address like this:

```
\image\carimage\2021_123test.jpg
```

Ok, when I want to show it in *Image.network('imageurl')* in flutter it is not possible to show that, because of backslash in path, I update one of iamge from database maunulay like this

```
/image/carimage/2021_123test.jpg
```

It work fine. In webpage I can see my images with previous path but in flutter I must change path, how can I do that dynamically

***Update:***

```
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('car pro '),
  ),
  body: controller.obx(
    (data) => Center(
      child: (Card(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image.network('http://mywebsite.com/' + data!['image']),

          ],
        ),
      )),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace all backlashes with the [`replaceAll`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) method:

```
String newImage = image.replaceAll(r'\', r'/');
```

**Edit:**

This solution wouldn't work since your image path would need to be a raw string, or contain double backlashes (`\\`). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713670/how-to-replace-backslash-with-double-backslash-in-dart). But if you add a double backslash to your image path when creating it in the database, then you can use:

```
Image.network("http://mywebsite.com/" +
                    data!['image'].replaceAll(r'\', r'/'))
```

Comment: I update my question, How can do that in middle of code.

Comment: @sunny See my edit